# Issue with Calculating Course Activity in a Learning System

Tags: java, logic, system

I have recently encountered a problem while implementing a learning system where I need to determine the activity of different courses based on student submissions. I have written code to calculate this, but I am getting incorrect results that do not meet the specific requirements of the task.

Here's an overview of the situation :

```
I have a list of course names: ["RIP", "Java", "AppMob", "BDD"]
I have a list of students with their grades for each course:
students = [
{id: 1, points: [8, 7, 7, 5]},
{id: 1, points: [7, 6, 9, 7]},
{id: 1, points: [6, 5, 5, 0]},
{id: 2, points: [8, 0, 8, 6]},
{id: 2, points: [7, 0, 0, 0]},
{id: 2, points: [9, 0, 0, 5]}
]
```

According to the task, the activity of a course is determined by the number of non-zero submissions from students. I need to find the course with the highest level of activity and the course with the lowest level of activity.

However, the code I have written so far does not seem to meet these requirements. It returns incorrect results where multiple courses are included in both the "highest activity" and "lowest activity" category. For example, the course "RIP" is listed as having both high activity and low activity.

Here's the code I used to calculate the course activity:

```
 public static class Activity {
        public static String getHighestActivityCourse() {
            int[] courseSubmissions = new int[courseNames.length];
            int highestSubmissions = 0;

            for (Etudiant etudiant : students) {
                int[] points = etudiant.getPoints();
                for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    if (points[i] > 0) {
                        courseSubmissions[i]++;
                        if (courseSubmissions[i] > highestSubmissions) {
                            highestSubmissions = courseSubmissions[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            List<String> highestActivityCourses = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < courseSubmissions.length; i++) {
                if (courseSubmissions[i] == highestSubmissions) {
                    highestActivityCourses.add(courseNames[i]);
                }
            }

            if (highestActivityCourses.isEmpty()) {
                return "n/a";
            } else {
                return String.join(", ", highestActivityCourses);
            }
        }

        public static String getLowestActivityCourse() {
            String highestActivityCourses = getHighestActivityCourse();
            List<String> lowestActivityCourses = new ArrayList<>();

            if (highestActivityCourses.equals("n/a")) {
                return "n/a";
            }

            Set<String> highestActivityCourseSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(highestActivityCourses.split(", ")));

            for (String courseName : courseNames) {
                if (!highestActivityCourseSet.contains(courseName)) {
                    lowestActivityCourses.add(courseName);
                }
            }

            if (lowestActivityCourses.isEmpty()) {
                return "n/a";
            }

            return String.join(", ", lowestActivityCourses);
        }
    }
```

I am aware that there is a problem in my calculation logic, but I am unable to resolve it correctly. I believe it has to do with how I count the student submissions and determine the highest level of activity.

I would like to ask for your assistance in understanding this issue and finding a proper solution. If you have any suggestions or modifications to improve my code, I am open to all ideas.

Thank you in advance for your valuable help!

Best regards

I tried implementing a code to calculate the activity of courses based on student submissions. I expected the code to correctly determine the course with the highest activity level and the course with the lowest activity level, considering the number of non-zero submissions for each course.

However, the results I obtained were not as expected. The code returned incorrect outcomes where multiple courses were listed in both the "highest activity" and "lowest activity" categories. This contradicts the requirements, as each course should only be included in one category.

I attempted to modify the logic for calculating activity by considering the number of non-zero submissions for each course. Unfortunately, my attempts did not yield the desired results.

I am now seeking guidance and assistance from the community to understand the issue and find a suitable solution.